# Prove that $\mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^s}$ is a rational function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, rational-functions, polylogarithm

> Polylogarithm:
>   $$\mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^s}$$
>   Prove that $\mathrm{Li}_s(x)$ is a rational function if $s\in\mathbb{Z},\ s\leqslant 0$.

I tried to find some sort of regularity by evaluating polylogarithm for different $s$:
$$
s=0:\ \  \mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}\\
s=-1:\ \ \mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
s=-2:\ \ \mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}\\
\vdots
$$
However, from $s=-3$ there is no regularity:
$$
s=-3:\ \ \mathrm{Li}_s(x)=\frac{x(x^2+4x+1)}{(1-x)^4}\\
\vdots
$$

So, I would be glad if someone could tell me what I should actually do in this problem.

Comment: Which operation leads from $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$ to $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} ka_k z^k$? Does this operation preserve rationality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\text{Li}_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\text{Li}_{n-1}(x)$$

then by induction if $\text{Li}_n(x)$ is rational, so is its derivative and hence $\text{Li}_{n-1}(x)$.

Comment: It turned out to be quite easy. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in a general formula, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) gives
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Li}_{-n}(x)&=\left(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^n\frac{z}{1-z}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left\{{{n+1}\atop{k+1}}\right\}k!}{(1-z)^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left<{{n}\atop{k}}\right>z^{n-k},
\end{align}$$
where $$\left\{{{n}\atop{k}}\right\}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i{k\choose i}(k-i)^n$$
are the Stirling numbers of the second kind, and 
$$\left<{{n}\atop{k}}\right>=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i{{n+1}\choose i}(k+1-i)^n$$
are the Eularian numbers.